# Typeahead only showing the exact match. How can I show all the data that is returned from remote url.?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I am facing a problem that I want to implement a search in which if you type the string with the double quotes("") it must also work.

Example: apple and "apple" both must return the same result

When I make the call to the backend, the call for both the search query is retuning the same thing but the typeahead filters the data somehow and the data does not get displayed in case of "apple".

I have tried using the filters like dropDownFilter and filter by assigning them false:

```
$('#searchInput').typeahead({ minLength: 1, order: "asc", delay: 500, 
                              dynamic: true, groupMaxItem: 6, highlight: false, 
                              hint: true, group: ["{{group}}, kind"], 
                              dropdownFilter: false,
```

But its not working, can anyone suggest me something.

Any help will be appreciated.!

Comment: can you include some code where the problem is occuring?

Comment: $('#searchInput').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    order: "asc",
    delay: 500,
    dynamic:true,
    groupMaxItem: 6,
    highlight:false,
    hint: true,
    group: ["{{group}},  kind"],
    dropdownFilter: false})

I tried this.!

Comment: how are you populating your data source?

Comment: I am using url  inside the source which populates the data.

Comment: are you ok with providing your own `matcher` function?

Comment: I can provide it. but i do not know how to do it and how does it work.. and i was not able to get much from the documentation too..
Could you please provide me an example for this case. 

I tried this :   `matcher:function(item){return true;}`

But it didn't worked. i was trying hit and try. Sorry if I was dumb with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing your own matcher function. Something along the lines of:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({source:myarray, matcher: function(item){
    // the regular expression will (optionally) consider double-quotes
    var reg = new RegExp('"?'+this.query+'"?');

    if( item.match(reg) ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }});
```